# Como fazer um regex que aceite uma linha mas não duas?

Tags: java, regex

Eu me perco ao fazer qualquer regex complexo.

Eu uso o seguinte codigo em java:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("tentativas de regex aki");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(conteudo);
while(matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

E para o regex  , ele deve fazer a seguinte busca:

[Qualquer caractere Especial] 
**[espaços livres(qualquer quantidade) que contenha no máximo 1 linha]** 
[letras] 
['não letra' (a primeiro q aparecer finaliza)]

Legenda:

1. linha - \n
2. espaço - ' '

**espaço livre** - 
Eu so pensei dessa maneira pq eu gostaria q ele finalizasse o regex apenas depois de vir a primeira letra, mas, não aceitasse se viessem duas linhas ou mais!

Alguém consegue converter isso pra regex?

Comment: qualquer quantidade de espaço ou linha?

Comment: Rodrigo, também não entendi o que seria esse "espaço ou linha". Também não entendi se pode ser "em qualquer quantidade" ou se deve ter apenas uma linha como diz o título. Poderia esclarecer essas dúvidas e colocar alguns exemplos de valores válidos e inválidos?

Comment: editei espero que ajude a compreender. E difícil até explicar ...

Comment: Coloque casos de teste que devem ser aceitos e que devem ser rejeitados.

Comment: Pelo que entendi basta você testar se existe uma quebra. Não é isso? Pois para uma única linha não existe quebra.

Comment: Seria algo como isso (qualquer coisa que não tenha uma quebra) : `/(.*)[^\n]+/`. [Exemplo](http://regexr.com/3cq78), se for percorrer tudo basta [fazer isso](http://regexr.com/3cq7b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se compreendi bem, mas:

```
([^\n]*\n)([a-zA-Z]+)([^a-zA-Z])
```

- `([^\n]*\n)` pega qualquer coisa ate encontrar um `\n`
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` a-zA-Z qualquer quantidade devendo ter ao menos 1
- `([^a-zA-Z])` qualquer coisa que não seja a-zA-Z, uma vez.

OBS.: `\n` = quebra de linha.

Comment: ([a-zA-Z]+) isso não é ao menos 1, (é 1 ou mais), para ao menos 1 use:([a-zA-Z]{1,}).

Comment: @IvanFerrer `+` em REGEX é a mesma coisa que `{1,}`, e `*` = `{0,}`

Comment: Bem, esse regex resolveu quase tudo! So troquei [^\n] por \W para pegar apenas caracteres especiais.